# What are some Alternative redirect methods to meta refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am redirecting to a new page after some specific time given by the user, like this :

```
html_meta_redirect( 'pagename?page_number='.$f_pageNumber, user_get_pref( 'refresh_delay' )*60 );
```

what are some alternate methods to implement this?

Comment: JavaScript code with setTimeout and window.location (but it'll work only with JavaScript enabled).

Comment: Or a `Location` header send with PHP's `header` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
  window.location = 'placed your URL here';
}
window.setTimeout('getLocation', 5000) // 5000 = 5 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
    header('location:welcome.html');
    ?>
```

the header will redirect to the welcome.html page 
Please note that there should not be any echo statements before the redirection

Comment: If you format your code better and add a simple explanation, this'll be nicer :)